# .so build error coming - please suggest (eclipse CDT cygwin)

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

**** Build of configuration Debug for project myso ****

make all

filename.d:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

The makefile looks like:

```
# All Target
all: libmyso.so
# Tool invocations
libmyso.so: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -L"E:\cygwin\lib" -shared -o"libmyso.so"
    $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(LIBRARIES)$(CPP_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) libmyso.so
    -@echo ' '
```

.PHONY: all clean dependents
   .SECONDARY: -include ../makefile.targets

Comment: You're going to need to add some useful information if you want a useful response.  For instance, the contents of the make file.

Comment: my make file : 

# All Target
all: libmyso.so

# Tool invocations
libmyso.so: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
 @echo 'Building target: $@'
 @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
 g++ -L"E:\cygwin\lib" -shared -o"libmyso.so" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
 @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
 @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
 -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(LIBRARIES)$(CPP_DEPS)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) libmyso.so
 -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets

Comment: FYI, console shows error in filename.d ..what is that?

Comment: also when I say build(clean project) this error doesnt come ..and i get .so file properly..

Answer (score 0):

The makefile that you posted (I hope I got the formatting correct) refers to another makefile, and the contents of that other makefile are probably important.  However, it appears that your problem is that [`filename.d` is found in a path with spaces](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119863), and that path is what appears in either `$(OBJS)` or `$(USER_OBJS)` (probably defined in `../makefile.targets`).

**EDIT** [It looks like this is a problem that has been fixed in some version of Make, but not yours](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/acro/wiki/FAQ) (see "Compiling on Cygwin").